# Add Control Panel items to Windows 8.1 Search

Tags: search, windows-8.1, control-panel

Windows 8.1 claims to search in all indexed locations.

However when I tried to open "Mail" (i.e. Mlcfg32.cpl) by typing "Mail" in Search, magic didn't happen. Instead I had to scramble all the way through Control Panel.

Is it possible to add Control Panel items to those indexed locations?
Or is it just the thing Microsoft forgot about? (e.g. forgot on intention, so users would make use of their new "Settings" applet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it fixed in Windows 8.1 Update 1.