# Windows 8.1 search not finding programs or control panel

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, windows-search

My problem is *similar* (although not *identical*, i.e. the solution is not the same) to the problem addressed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/694521/windows-8-1-search-not-finding-control-panel-settings). In short, neither Control panels (i.e. Update, NVIDIA, Display) or Programs (in the C:\Program Files(x86) directory) show up in my Metro UI/Charms/Modern UI search tab (i.e. Win+S -- even under the "Search everywhere" search tab and with the "allow files on the drive to have content indexed..." box in the relevant folder options ticked.

I've found out that Control panels do show up again if I turn off the Windows Search service. But then it's my personal files (names or content) that no longer show up in the Metro UI/charms/Modern UI search tab.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/865496/cant-find-computermanegment-by-searching-in-windows-8-1

Comment: You should really read before using "signal possible duplicate". It helps.

Comment: **The original revision didn't have a link, all it said was here, and linked to nothing**  SO how is this question different from the linked question exactly?

Comment: You can find `Control Panel` on the CTRL+I charm. Sounds like you don't have all [available updates installed](http://superuser.com/questions/670420/add-control-panel-items-to-windows-8-1-search?rq=1).

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1, latest build. My problem is not that I cannot access Control Panel. My problem is that I cannot access Control panel from the search function located in the right-border tab (new interface, i.e. Win+S) while I remember being able to do so. I can only access my personal documents from here.